# Pytorch rename labels of a trained model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, categorical-data

I have a trained model. During training there was some problem with string characters. So i converted my labels into numbers like:

`red : 0`

`blue: 1`

`green: 2`

Now is it possible to rename my label back to actual label names.
Hours of training. Would be  helpful if anyone has an idea.

Train and validate the model

```
for epoch in range(1, epoch_num + 1):
    loss_train, acc_train = train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
    loss_val, acc_val = validate(val_loader, model, criterion, epoch)
    total_loss_val.append(loss_val)
    total_acc_val.append(acc_val)
```

Test Single Image:

```
def eval_image(file_path):
    model = torch.load(file_path)
    model.eval()
    device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    X = Image.open('red.jpeg')
    test_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
    image_tensor = test_transforms(X).float()
    image_tensor = image_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)
    input = Variable(image_tensor)
    input = input.to(device)
    output = model(input)
    index = output.data.cpu().numpy().argmax()
    print(index)
```

Once the training is done, The evaluation script cannot be made generic. I will have to pass following code

```
idx_to_class = {
        0: "red",
        1: "blue",
        2: "green",
    }
    class_name = idx_to_class[index]
```

But I do not want to pass the above code. As my evaluation script needs to generic.

Comment: Based on your comments to one of the answers, your question needs more details.

Comment: I guess now its explainable

Comment: I guess you misunderstood one of the comments: Keras does *not* have these `model.universe` and `model.num2label`. How was the file in `file_path` generated? `torch.save(model)`?

Comment: Yes .. torch.save() was used

Comment: I asked, because as you're looking for a generic eval script, saving a model like this (which is [not the recommended way to do it](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-model-for-inference)) imposes some restrictions on the evaluation

Comment: Since it looks like you don't care about these restrictions, you could just save a dict as suggested in both the answers you had so far in an attribute such as `num2label` and add a `model.num2label[index]` in the end of your eval script... it will be generic (you can even check if this attribute exists in case you don't set it for all your models).

Comment: I have saved everything in a dict and passing the .txt file and model file for the generic eval script. I removed the torch.save() and using state_dict to load. The eval script uses another script which has ```Model(nn.module)``` That was nice to know. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary for it!

```
labels = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1]

dct = {0: "red", 1: "blue", 2: "green"}

renamed_labels = [dct[x] for x in labels]

renamed_labels ## ["red", "blue", "green", "blue", "red", "green", "blue"]
```

Comment: In the trained model. After training I would like to replace in the state_dict of the trained PyTorch model. This solution would not help I guess!

Comment: but labels must be numbers - so that training works. I don't know PyTorch yet. But in Tensorflow/keras, you also get when predicting numbers - and re-translate back to the actual labels. Labels must be numeric values or one hot encoded values.

Comment: The testing script is generic for multiple models. I don't want to pass anything else other than image.

Comment: why you then not integrate this step into the predict function/method then?

Comment: can you lookup from model or state_dict the original names of the classes? the "universe" of the classes? Usually one cannot in keras models. So one has pass the information to the re-translator function/method outside the model.

Comment: I tried, but i kinda failed so i posted the question here

Comment: you have to catch this info when you are translating the original labels to numbers. do you use scikit-learn class to do that?

Comment: I do before turning dataset to tensors. I'm using pandas. I know the mapping, i just need to put it back to model

Comment: in keras, there is no place for that in model. Well, but you could attach it yourself to model. by attaching an attribute e.g. `model.universe = ["red", "blue", "green"]` - well that would be just a hack. or even `model.num2label = {0: "red", 1: "blue", 2: "green"}`

Comment: Exactly, this is what I'm looking for but in Pytorch

Comment: there won't be because you have to give in the info. the model sees for training only the numbers you created for labels. So no way to get information for the model which was original label. that is you have to provide yourself the info to the model - or keep the info outside the model by yourself.

Comment: I understood what you are saying. I can provide that and save the model again so that the evaluation script will be still generic. But i did not find the function under pytorch. Have posted the ques in Pytorch help group

Comment: maybe if you post parts of your scripts I/one can help you.

Comment: Ok! I will do it .. Thanks

Comment: @Praveen there are thousands of ways to make it work, but all of them will be customized... for instance, one can overwrite the function that generates the state_dict to carry this information alongside the modules/parameters/buffers...

Answer (score -1):

```
labels = ["red", "blue", "green"]
dataset = ["red", "blue", "green", "green", "green", "red", "blue"]
```

Create label dictionary:

```
l_dict = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(labels)}
print(l_dict)
```

> Output: `{'red': 0, 'blue': 1, 'green': 2}`

```
l_dict_reverse = {k:v for k, v in enumerate(labels)}
print(l_dict_reverse)
```

> Output: `{0: 'red', 1: 'blue', 2: 'green'}`

```
char_to_num = [l_dict[x] for x in dataset]
print(char_to_num)
```

> Output: `[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1]`

```
num_to_char = [l_dict_reverse[x] for x in char_to_num]
print(num_to_char)
```

> Output: `['red', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'blue']`

**Complete code snippet:**

```
labels = ["red", "blue", "green"]
dataset = ["red", "blue", "green", "green", "green", "red", "blue"] 

l_dict = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(labels)}
# Output: {'red': 0, 'blue': 1, 'green': 2}

l_dict_reverse = {k:v for k, v in enumerate(labels)}
# Output: {0: 'red', 1: 'blue', 2: 'green'}

char_to_num = [l_dict[x] for x in dataset]
# Output: `[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1]

num_to_char = [l_dict_reverse[x] for x in char_to_num]
# Output: `['red', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'blue']
```